# C# Winform - Learning async/await - How to update progressbar

Tags: c#, async-await, progress-bar

I have a simple winform with one button and a toolstripprogressbar. The code behind the buttons is :

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var path = @"W:\Records";

            var files = DirectoryLister.GetFileNames(path);

        });
    }
```

Clicking the button calls a static method in a static class, which returns an `IEnumerable<string>` containing the filenames in the path and its subdirectories.

I'm trying to update the progressbar as this is happening but unsure of how to go about it. In the past I have used a backgroundworker but now I'm trying out this async way.

Comment: Just use IProgress<T>. Read about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/).

Answer (score -2):

Create an event and raise it with a status of your progress. The main thread can subscribe to this event via a delegate function, which in turn updates your progress bar.

Comment: This is a comment-quality answer.